# Why does adding contents to a div add a scrollbar to the page when parent size is constant?

Tags: html, css

See the HTML and CSS below.

When the h1 tag is uncommented, a scrollbar is added to the page, but I don't know why. I suspect it's because the cards have `position:fixed`, but I don't know how to get them to look like that any other way besides `position:fixed`.

I would like the `title` div to take up 20% of the screen and the `card-conveyor-belt` div to take up 80% of the screen, regardless of their contents. How can I go about doing this?

HTML:

```
<body>
<div class="title">
  <!--
  <h1>
  HELLO
  </h1>-->
</div>
<div class="card-conveyor-belt">
  <div class="card left"></div>
  <div class="card center"></div>
  <div class="card right"></div>

</div>
</body>
```

CSS

```
html,body{
  height:100%;
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
    background-color:#ccc;
}
.title{height: 20%;width: 100%;}
.card-conveyor-belt{
  height: 80%;
  width: 100%;

 }

.card{
  position:fixed;
  width:80%;
  height:80%;
  background-color:white;
  border-radius:5px;
}
.center{
  left:10%;
}
.left{
  left:-78%;
}
.right{
  left:98%;
}
```

[Here is the same code in a jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/84xqzjur/2/) if you'd like to run/interact with it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply use `margin: 0` to fix your problem:

Jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/dj3mabgz/

```
h1 {
  margin: 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks. Why do margins cause a scrollbar though when it seems it's contained within the title div?

Comment: Another way to solve this problem is to do `h1 {display: inline-block}` in that case you don't "loose" the margin.

Comment: It may be due to the size of the h1 overlapping the div, you could also try using CSS Normalize to avoid annoying html/css glitches like this.

Answer (score 0):

Like the other answer stated, the issue is with the margin on the `<h1>` tag. By default (at least in Chrome it is default, not certain about other browsers), all `<h1>` tags have a default margin top value of 0.67em. 
Now, since you didn't define where you wanted to position the block inside your `.title` block, it automatically positioned it at the top. So the result is as you can see in the picture; [image]

The default margin and the default positioning ends up "pushing" all of the content down and forcing the scrollbar to appear.